# How to add piwik JavaScript Tracking Tag to whole project files?

Tags: php

Recently I have installed piwik in my local wamp server.
Copied unzipped piwik folder to *c:\wamp\www* and opened the URl *localhost/piwik*

Installed piwik successfully with my own php project as web site **"localhost/myproj"**,

I have so many files in my project ,copying the piwik **JavaScript Tracking Tag** to all files is not that much easy.

I have searched in google and read about the plugins to integrate that JavaScript Tracking Tag.

But I have no idea of how to do that?

Need to uninstall piwik for installing plugin? is there any other way to that?.

Please suggest me.

Comment: What you're asking is unclear (to me). Pretty much, it seems that this question is completely unrelated to piwik, and you want to add some JS to every page in your project. Since you're mentionning PHP, and I don't know if you're using a framework or not (I hope you are), your pages should use a master layout that include the JS tracking snippet.

Comment: While installing piwik there is a step for *JavaScript Tracking Tag* .We should add this in all files then only we can able to track the page using piwik.

Comment: MY question is instead of copying that *javaScript Tracking Tag* snippet in each and every page,is there any way to default to add those snippet in our project

Comment: My upper comment still applies :) Your pages/views should use a master layout.

Comment: Can you please give a detailed view of master layout.?..I am using php storm editer,,is this really needed?

Comment: Unrelated to PHPStorm. If you're saying you have many files/pages, does that mean you are duplicating the HTML for every page? `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: Kind of..some pages has different structure,So i have used for every page

Comment: Well I strongly recommend a templating engine and/or a framework, in that case. It's beyond your need, but it's best practice. Otherwise, quick and dirty solution: run a search/replace in your files to append the script.

Comment: Can we use any plugins for this purpose?

Comment: Search/replace is a feature built in

Comment: No,What am asking is plugins like wordpress/Drupal with piwik to make this easy..I just read in google..but not sure how to use?..Do you have any idea?

Comment: So you are using Wordpress/Joomla? Just append it to your header/footer template. Otherwise I'm sure there are plugins to append scripts and what not for non-developers, but it's easy enough that a plugin is not necessary

Comment: I am not using any plugins now..Just thinking about that.Do we need to install wordpress before installing piwik?..do you know the steps?

Comment: The order is not important

Comment: I don't know Piwik, I just assume they give you a <script> tag that you append to your pages. It's definitely not rocket science

Comment: ok.thanks for your time.:-)